# Fibonacci series not working due to logical implementation error in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, fibonacci

Starter with the logic implementation through programming so please find my honest efforts for project Euler Ques, although i tried various attempts to solve but could not get through it :(

Sum I am getting from this is - `257112`. I added +2 in the sum to count for `a[1] = 2` in the series, but its not working, also I am currently passing a static value `45` for `$num` but i think it is not the correct way, let me know where I am lagging in logic for the question.

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

this is the code I tried -->

```
$a = array();
$a[0] = 1; $a[1] = 2; $num = 45; $i= 0; $sum = 0; $stop = $num -2;
    for($i; $i < $stop ; $i++ ) {
    $a[$i+2] = $a[$i+1] + $a[$i];

            if( $a[$i+2]%2 == 0 && $a[$i+2] <= 400000 )
            {
            $sum += $a[$i+2]; 
            }

    }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "<br>"."Sum is : ".$sum;
```

**EDIT** - It was an error to add an extra zero to make it 4 million, although I am looking something for $num not to be static (as 45 I just mentioned randomly, although its working but its not a clean solution)

Comment: Sorry my bad it was just to add an extra zero 400000 => 4000000.. although please suggest for $num, as I dont want it to pass static like what i am doing this time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it simple, no arrays and make it quick.  You are only looking for the sum, nothing else:

```
$a=1;$b=2;$sum=2;
while($b<4000000){
    $c=$b+$a;
    if($c%2==0)
        $sum+=$c;
    $a=$b;
    $b=$c;
}
echo $sum;
```

If 4,000,000 counted, then it would be `$b<=4000000`

Comment: Awesome..very clean and a good concept to follow..thx I am just a starter so finding these things little hard to follow on my own :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$f0=0;/* declaring variables */
$f1=1;
$f2=0;

$n=0; /* the series range */

while($n<20)
{
 $f2=$f0+$f1;
 echo $f2."<br>";
 $f0=$f1;
 $f1=$f2;
 $n++;
}
?>
```

Comment: i guess, we both have followed the same procedure and copied same piece of code from same page. Very rare incident. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$f0=0;/* declaring variables */
$f1=1;
$f2=0;

$n=0; /* the series range */

while($n < $stop){
    $f2=$f0+$f1;
    $temp[] = $f2;
    $f0=$f1;
    $f1=$f2;
    $n++;
}

var_dump($temp);
?>
```

You can check out same example [here](http://gauri1234.hubpages.com/hub/Displaying-Fibonacci-series)

Comment: I am looking for code refinement and logical exposure, not just another thing to make things work :)

Comment: @user1594368: Sorry, but i didnt understand your comment. What are you saying? You want to know how it works? want comments in answer that can explain each step and their significance?

Comment: I just made an edit to my question..after your lightning fast answer :)

Comment: if you want dynamic value, then you will have to use forms or ajax to pass dynamic value to php logic. Do you need help in making a form and passing value to PHP logic?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple:

```
$prev = 0;
$curr = 1;
$next = 1;
for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $prev = $next;
    $curr = $i;
    $next = $prev + $curr;
    echo $next.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fibonacci_series($n) {
 $f1 = -1;
 $f2 = 1;

 for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
   $f = $f1 + $f2;
   $f1 = $f2;
   $f2 = $f;
   echo "$f<br />"; 
 }
}

echo fibonacci_series(5);
```